# Extract Twitch ursername from url

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match, twitch

I'm trying to validate if a given url is a twitch.tv one and then extract the channel name from it. I came up with this regex:

```
preg_match("/^[(http|https):\/\/www.twitch.tv\/]+((?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w]{3,24}))$/", $url, $output_array);
```

I seems to work but only if the the first characters of the username are not one of these (w, t, p, s, h, c, v, b)

For example if I enter the url: `https://www.twitch.tv/AchannelName`
It will output:

> 0=>`https://www.twitch.tv/AchannelName`
>
> 1=>**AchannelName**

But for the following url: `https://www.twitch.tv/`channelName`
It will output:

> 0=>`https://www.twitch.tv/channelName`
>
> 1=>**annelName**

PS: I am using [a-zA-Z0-9] because the username cannot start with underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Then use

```
 $4
```

Comment: I tried it like that: 
`preg_match("/^[(http|https):\/\/www\.twitch\.tv\/]+((#)?[a-zA-Z0-9][\w]{2,24})$/", $input_line, $output_array);`
and I didn't work, it has the same effect... Just skips the characters (w, t, p, s, h, c, v)
You can test it here http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: Hey I updated my answer! Its a bit different approach but should be useful @DiyanDesigns

Comment: Thanks for your time, I bet it works but I already fixed my problem by adding the Ungreedy option @Vedant

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by adding the Ungreedy flag to my regex
Here is the working code:

> preg_match("/^[(http|https)://www.twitch.tv/]+((#)?[a-zA-Z0-9][\w]{2,24})$/**U**",
>   $url, $m)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the built in PHP function parse_url. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php. This will give you all parts of the URL and the channel name like this:  /channelname.

UPDATED ANSWER After new info.

```
$url = "https://www.twitch.tv/channelName";

$urls = parse_url($url);


if(isset($urls['host']) && $urls['host'] == 'www.twitch.tv') {

  $id = ltrim($urls['path'],'/'); }else{ $id = 0; }

echo $id;
```

Comment: I already tried it but for some reason it didn't work: here is my code: 

`$urls = parse_url($url); 
                if(isset($urls['host']) && $urls['host'] == 'twitch.tv'){  
                    $id = ltrim($urls['path'],'/'); 
                }else{
                    $id = 0;
                } `

Comment: Yes, because $urls['host'] == 'twitch.tv' is false. It should be $urls['host == "www.twitch.tv".

So it should be: 

'$url = "https://www.twitch.tv/channelName";

$urls = parse_url($url);

print_r($urls);

if(isset($urls['host']) && $urls['host'] == 'www.twitch.tv'){ $id = ltrim($urls['path'],'/'); }else{ $id = 0; }

echo $id;'